# Can I use the full user-agent string?

Tags: cordova, ionic3, user-agent

When I send requests from my app's front-end, user-agent strings like

```
myAppName/6.0.6272 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.3.0
```

get included, but when I send from a plugin, something like

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148
```

is used.

It looks to me like something in the front-end is overriding the user-agent - is there a way to turn that off so I can get the 2nd format consistently?

Comment: What plugin and when doing exactly what? This question should be posted on the plugin's **Issues section of GitHub** anyway.

Comment: @andreszs I don't know what is replacing the user-agent - how could I figure that out? I did some searches and it wasn't obvious.